# How can I add text labels to a Plotly scatter plot in Python?

Tags: python, plotly

I'm trying to add text labels next to the data points in a Plotly scatter plot in Python but I get an error.

How can I do that?

Here is my dataframe:

```
world_rank  university_name country teaching    international   research    citations   income  total_score num_students    student_staff_ratio international_students  female_male_ratio   year
0   1   Harvard University  United States of America    99.7    72.4    98.7    98.8    34.5    96.1    20,152  8.9 25% NaN 2011
```

Here is my code snippet:

```
citation = go.Scatter(
                    x = "World Rank" + timesData_df_top_50["world_rank"],  <--- error
                    y = "Citation" + timesData_df_top_50["citations"], <--- error
                    mode = "lines+markers",
                    name = "citations",
                    marker = dict(color = 'rgba(48, 217, 189, 1)'),
                    text= timesData_df_top_50["university_name"])
```

The error is shown below.

```
TypeError: ufunc 'add' did not contain a loop with signature matching types dtype('<U32') dtype('<U32') dtype('<U32')
```

Comment: Could you please share the first few rows of your data frame?

Comment: Thank you. The error is due to the fact that you are trying to add a string (e.g. "Citation") to a float (e.g. 98.8), what are you trying to achieve exactly? Do you want to display some text next to each point on the scatter plot? Or do you want to change the axes titles?

Comment: @gflavia I want to display some text next to each point on the scatter plot.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Plotly: How to annotate figure by a list of strings and a list of coordinates?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60975457/plotly-how-to-annotate-figure-by-a-list-of-strings-and-a-list-of-coordinates)

Answer (score 36, accepted):

You can include the text labels in the `text` attribute. To make sure that they are displayed on the scatter plot, set `mode='lines+markers+text'`. See the [Plotly documentation on text and annotations](https://plotly.com/python/text-and-annotations/#text-on-scatter-plots-with-graph-objects). I included an example below based on your code.

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'world_rank': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
                   'university_name': ['Harvard', 'MIT', 'Stanford', 'Cambridge', 'Oxford'],
                   'citations': [98.8, 98.7, 97.6, 97.5, 96]})

layout = dict(plot_bgcolor='white',
              margin=dict(t=20, l=20, r=20, b=20),
              xaxis=dict(title='World Rank',
                         range=[0.9, 5.5],
                         linecolor='#d9d9d9',
                         showgrid=False,
                         mirror=True),
              yaxis=dict(title='Citations',
                         range=[95.5, 99.5],
                         linecolor='#d9d9d9',
                         showgrid=False,
                         mirror=True))

data = go.Scatter(x=df['world_rank'],
                  y=df['citations'],
                  text=df['university_name'],
                  textposition='top right',
                  textfont=dict(color='#E58606'),
                  mode='lines+markers+text',
                  marker=dict(color='#5D69B1', size=8),
                  line=dict(color='#52BCA3', width=1, dash='dash'),
                  name='citations')

fig = go.Figure(data=data, layout=layout)

fig.show()
```