# Is there a way to put static labels next to points on a scatterplot in python?

Tags: python, plotly, visualization, geospatial

I currently have a dataframe that looks something like this:

| Name | Count | Latitude | Longtitude |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| place1 | 12 | 38 | -121 |
| place2 | 39 | 37 | -119 |

I want to visualize these over a map - and this the plotly code I have as of now:

```
import plotly.express as px

fig = px.scatter_mapbox(df, lat="Latitude", lon="Longitude", 
                        size="Count",
                        zoom=5,
                        mapbox_style="carto-positron",
                        text="Name",
                        opacity=0.4)

fig.show()
```

Now, using parameters like `tooltip` or `hover_data` make the `Name` of each place show up when the mouse hovers over it. But I'd like these to be static labels. I saw a very similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61342459/how-can-i-add-text-labels-to-a-plotly-scatter-plot-in-python#:%7E:text=You%20can%20include%20the%20text,documentation%20on%20text%20and%20annotations.) but that only seems to deal with the `.Scatter` method - which has a parameter `mode` that `scatter_mapbox` does not have.

Comment: doesn't the argument `text="Name"` produce static labels corresponding to the `Name` column in your dataframe? what does your current scatter mapbox look like?

Comment: I have the `text` argument- this is what it looks like currently: https://i.imgur.com/4voWyOe.jpg

Answer (score 2):

Annotating on a map is possible with a graph object. To create one, you will need to obtain a free Mapbox API token in advance; see [here](https://plotly.com/python/mapbox-layers/#mapbox-access-tokens-and-when-you-need-them) to obtain the API. To create the graph, `go.Scattertermapbox()` sets the mode for markers and text, and sets the size of markers and text decoration, respectively. For layout, we set the center, mapbox style and API key. If you need a legend, you will need to set the name of the data frame in a looping process. The reference has an [example](https://plotly.com/python/scattermapbox/#multiple-markers) similar to your question.

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go

mapbox_access_token = open("mapbox_api_key.txt").read()

fig = go.Figure()

fig.add_trace(go.Scattermapbox(mode='markers+text',
                               lat=df['Latitude'],
                               lon=df['Longitude'],
                               marker=go.scattermapbox.Marker(
                                   size=df['Count'],
                                   color='blue',
                                   opacity=0.4
                               ),
                               text=df['Name'],
                               textfont=dict(size=12,color='red'),
                               textposition='bottom center'
                              )
             )

fig.update_layout(
    autosize=True,
    hovermode='closest',
    mapbox=dict(
        accesstoken=mapbox_access_token,
        style="light",
        bearing=0,
        center=dict(
            lat=df['Latitude'].mean(),
            lon=df['Longitude'].mean()
        ),
        pitch=0,
        zoom=5
    ),
)

fig.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer! The mapbox website seems to be down for me at the moment; I'll try and create an account and let you know what happens afterwards.